# Ubuntu 14.04.2 won't start up

Tags: boot

Ubuntu boots into a console instead of the graphical interface.

This is the result:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Ubuntu tty1

ubuntu login: steven
Password:
Last login: Mon Jul 20 05:51:12 EDT 2015 on tty1
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-30-generic x86_64)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
steven@ubuntu:~$ _
```

I’m not sure how to make Ubuntu boot up from this stage.

Comment: It does start up. You probably installed a server version.

Comment: is there a link to ubuntu it's self?

Comment: It is Ubuntu itself. Please tell what distribution did you install. What file did you download as Ubuntu. Give a link.

Comment: I think i got it now. is this the link fro ubuntu? http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Right. And what did you install?

Comment: The 64-bit version.

Comment: They both server and desktop have 64 versions.

Comment: What is file name you downloaded?

Comment: http://gyazo.com/8e3579f0c8a899fe903ab1d983bdfba1

Comment: Looks like a desktop.

Comment: @StevenHines. Why send us away to another website to look at an image of some text? Why not write the text here? `ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso.crdownload`.

Comment: Note that `.crdownload` indicates an incomplete download. If you tried installing from that, you should expect all kinds of weirdness. Try again, this time waiting for the download to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed Ubuntu server instead of desktop.

Server version does not have a graphical interface.

You can download and install Ubuntu Desktop or run in console

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, you said that the name of the file you used was `ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso.crdownload`. The extension `.crdownload` indicates an incompletely downloaded file. If you installed from this, you should expect all kinds of weirdness. It may be possible to recover this system, but my suggestion would be to try again from scratch.

1. Download the file again, this time waiting for the download to complete. The `.crdownload` extension should be removed: the completely downloaded file is called `ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso`.
2. Install again, as you did before, but this time using the complete `.iso` file. It should work properly this time.

Frankly, I’m astonished it worked at all.

Answer (score -1):

If you find you do have ubuntu-desktop installed, execute the following:

`gdm`

It should fire up the GUI login page if it's configured correctly.